# How to Declare A String ina String

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax

I am a newbie in programming and I have a PHP code where I need to connect to the database.
I have a line like this:

```
$where = 'module = "Card"';
$arrDateInfo = $objQuery->select($col, $table, $where);
```

However this part 'module = "Card"' is not right. I want to get only the data where the module is "Card". Having another table for the module_type is not an option. I cannot find anywhere how to declare a string inside a longer string. Please help!

Comment: It's part of SC_Query_Ex::getSingletonInstance() defined function in EC-Cube. I am not actually that good with the terms, sorry I did not include that.

Comment: What is the issue you're having with the code as given? In what way is it "not right"?

Comment: the 'module = "Card"' is wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on the database you use, you're going to want to use single quotes around the string in the where clause.  I suggest swapping the quotes used, like this:

```
$where = "module = 'Card'";
$arrDateInfo = $objQuery->select($col, $table, $where);
```

Comment: `$where = 'module = "Card"';` === `$where = "module = 'Card'";`

Comment: Fabrizio: While PHP treats that the same, databases don't.  It may work as written in MySQL.  If it's MSSQL, you can't use double quotes to identify a string.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good chance that `$where` is expecting an associative array.

try this:

```
$where = array(
    'module' => 'Card'
);
```

Though, unless you tell us what DB library we're using, we wont know what it expects without being able to look up the function in the documentation for said library.

Comment: thanks! this is a good option but I fixed mine using  "module = 'Card'" with the double quote on the outside instead and the single quote inside. i gave you an UP vote anyhow.